# Using exec() in php via web

Tags: php

Hello i was trying to use `exec()` in php via web page to execute a file in the root directory, and for some reason none of my commands work except

```
    ls
```

witch even when i do

```
    ls /root
```

it doesn't work seems i can only do ls in the current directory or commands like `whoami` which returns `apache`

i've tried setting user permissions for apache, and i've tried setting permissions for file or `/var/www/html` directory and nothing seems to work any ideas?, my basic code below

```
<?php
    command = "ls /root";
    exec($command);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exec command return only the last line of your command.

Like said in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php), you should add a second parameter to get the result or use the function [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.passthru.php)

Comment: hello, i tried passthru and it seems to return everything but for some reason i still cant access /root or any directories in there only /var/www/html and / itself, any ideas? i think it could be permission wise